# What preposition should be used with "cache"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Which is most grammatical?

> - It's still cached *to* your phone.
> - It's still cached *in* your phone.
> - It's still cached *on* your phone.

I find myself gravitating towards "to" but I'm not sure - I feel like "cached" implies some kind of attachment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*To cache* something means to store it away, so I think the most natural preposition is ***in***. *Cached on* is also fairly common.

*Cached to* is very uncommon, but appears to becoming more popular in software contexts. I suspect this is because non-software caches usually require you to be close to them, but software caches are often remote so that the act of caching involves sending data *to* another server. Because your phone is not a remote server *cached to* is an unnatural choice.

You can see the relative uses of these prepositions with [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cached+in%2C+cached+on%2C+cached+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccached%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccached%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccached%20to%3B%2Cc0).

[image: A Google ngram chart showing significantly more usage of "cached in" over time versus "cached on". "cached to" is barely represented in the graph, but has increased slightly since the mid 1990s.]

Comment: That's my feeling, too, but is there evidence? [Maybe some ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cached+on%2Ccached+in%2Ccached+to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccached%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccached%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcached%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCached%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccached%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcached%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCached%20to%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: @curiousdannii "Cache" is used more generally than in computing, as you can see from the fact that "cached in" and "cached on" were more widely used in 1945 than at any time in the period 1950-1990. Terrorists cache their weapons *in* the forest to stop the police finding them, squirrels cache their nuts *in* the ground to store them over the winter. So the NGrams say very little.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't see how the type of cache will determine how the word is used. It's still the same sense of the word.

Comment: @curiousdannii If a squirrel cached its nuts *on* the ground, some other squirrel would take them. If a terrorist cached his weapons *on* the forest, ... what would that even mean? The type of cache absolutely affects the preposition that is used.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's true. Or for all we know maybe the uses of *on* are all adjuncts like "cached on Tuesday"!

Comment: @curiousdannii And "*cached to* stop the other squirrels stealing them".

Comment: Though the data does suggest that *cached to* is becoming more common with technology. I think this usage parallels usages like *stored to the database* or *synchronised to Dropbox*.

Comment: @curious I find _stored to the database_ quite odd (I would always use _in_ here, since _store_ is the result of saving, i.e., what comes _after_ the ‘movement’ into the database or onto the disk), but I think of _cached to your phone_ as exactly equivalent to _synchronised to your Dropbox_. Note that little word _still_ in the question, though. If something is _still_ cached, that's a state, and I'd never use _to_. After you cache it _to_ the phone, it's cached _on_ the phone.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good point about *still cached*! None of the answers have addressed the stative use in the question but I agree that's crucial... feel free to edit this answer or write your own if you like.

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent answers. I'd say that prevalence of usage is a strong argument for what is most grammatical, so I went with this answer. I think that part of the reason I felt an association with "attachment" is the de facto nature of phone caches to be transitory, and "to" felt like the most impermanent preposition.

Answer (score 2):

To *cache* is to store something away for future use (especially if in a hidden place).  You could store things *in* a box or *on* a shelf but I can't think of any situation in which you'd store something *to* somewhere. One normally talks about storing things *on* a particular computer/disk/memory stick so I would use the same for cache.

Comment: *Save to disk*?

Comment: @bib What of it? Just because *save* uses *to* doesn't mean any other word does.

Comment: @curiousdannii DR's answer argues that you don't *store something **to** somewhere*. When you *save to disk*, you are storing something *to* a disk. It doesn;t mean the other prepositions are wrong, just that *to* is not ruled out.  Whether *cache* takes *to* is more a function of usage than pure logic.

Comment: @bib No, when you save *to* a disk, you're storing something *on* it.

Comment: It's a question of language, not logic. you are actually storing something *in* the magnetic medium *on* the disk.

Comment: as far as computer science, the cache is a physical location, as well as a verb. "The phone has cached it, so it's in the phone's cache."

Comment: @BenPlont I agree that it's "in the phone's cache" but that doesn't imply that it's "cached in the phone" rather than "on".

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, I should have specified that the phone's memory is a container, not a surface. So, to me, in is a more suitable preposition.